# Erro no Chrome ao decodificar acentos postados via HTTP POST

Tags: http, codificação-de-caracteres, post

Possuo um formulário que faz uma requisição HTTP POST para atualizar o BD. Durante a requisição notei que apareceu a seguinte mensagem para um campo preenchido com acentuação no Chrome Dev Tool. Por exemplo, a avaliação é exibida como `avalia%E7%E3o`.

> unable to decode value

A codificação da página e do browser são ISO-8859-1. O PHP recebe o texto do campo com acento como sendo um HTML Numeric Entity, não interpreta corretamente e grava "vazio" no Banco.

Possuo um outro servidor com as mesmas configurações e fontes, e este problema não ocorre, isto é, avaliação (por exemplo) é gravado corretamente no Banco. Por que esse problema ocorre? Qual poderia ser a causa do meu outro servidor com o mesmo browser e fontes funcionar?

Comment: Só para entender melhor, você tem um formulário e ao submeter ele os dados recebidos chegam codificados é isto?

Comment: O seu form já está com application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Answer (score 1):

Experimenta alterar a codificação da página que envia as variáveis e a que recebe para windows-1252.
Julgo que o ISO-8859-1 não mostra os caracteres expeciais

Comment: desculpa, esquecime de dizer que o header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=window-1252'); no topo da página que recebe, tambem ajuda a mostrar os caracteres